# autologout jQuery working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery

Im creating an auto logout after a certain amount of time. It works in Google Chrome but not in Firefox. (It makes the page jump up and down and shows the dialog box at the bottom and leaves a lot of white space)

This is the orginal code: https://forums.asp.net/t/1899214.aspx?If+no+activity+for+15+minutes+display+an+alert+on+web+page+and+then+either+continue+or+logout

This is my code:

```
<div id="timeout" class="niceBox" visible="false" >
    <h1>Session About To Timeout</h1>
    <p>You will be automatically logged out in 1 minute.<br />
    To remain logged in move your mouse.
</div>


    <style>

        .niceBox
            {
                background-color: #ecf0f1;
                border: 1px solid #0DA9D0;
                padding: 20px;
                }

         #timeout {
            display: none;
        }  

    </style>



<script type="text/javascript">
     // Set timeout variables.
     var timoutWarning123 = 3000; // Display warning
     var timoutNow123 = 6000; // Timeout
     var logoutUrl123 = '/login.aspx'; // URL to logout page.

     var warningTimer123;
     var timeoutTimer123;

     // Start timers.
     function StartTimers123() {
         warningTimer123 = setTimeout("IdleWarning123()", timoutWarning123);
         timeoutTimer123 = setTimeout("IdleTimeout123()", timoutNow123);
     }

     // Reset timers.
     function ResetTimers123() {
         clearTimeout(warningTimer123);
         clearTimeout(timeoutTimer123);
         StartTimers123();
         $("#timeout").dialog('close');
     }

     // Show idle timeout warning dialog.
     function IdleWarning123() {
         $("#timeout").dialog({
             modal: false
         });
     }

     // Logout the user.
     function IdleTimeout123() {
         window.location = logoutUrl123;
     }


     $('*').mouseenter(function() {
        ResetTimers123()
     });

     $(document).keyup(function() {
        ResetTimers123()
     });
<script>
```

Comment: The only thing I see that can be an issue is the first argument of both `setTimeout` where the function name should be passed without quotes and without parenthesis. You say that works on Chrome?

Comment: That is an inactivity redirection... There's nothing about logging in or out, by the way.

Comment: yes it works in chrome. Also, I've removed the quotes and parenthesis and it's the same problem

Comment: I'm not sure about your issue... But trying to recreate it [**here**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ajRNQg?editors=1011), it seems to be working fine in FF. The only thing I changed is to comment out `$("#timeout").dialog('close');` in `function ResetTimers123()` because it was throwing an error in console `cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`.

Comment: And I would suggest `$(document).mousemove(...)` instead of `$('*').mouseenter(...)`.

Comment: I always have some other jquery code on the page. Do you think that'll affect it?

Comment: I can't tell. Look at the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for errors. Use some [console logs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to debug... Good luck.